# Intermittent "Owner resource does not exist"

Tags: c#, azure-cosmosdb

I am using DocumentDb v1.8.0 and when checking if a collection exists it will return a 404 error. If I get that error, I then try to create the collection and that returns a 409 error (resource already exists).

I have four collections and one of them randomly fails every time this check is done. The databases/collections are not being deleted so I am at a loss as to why this is happening.

some other information:

- The collections IndexingMode is consistent
- ConnectionMode is direct
- Protocol is TCP

Update with stacktrace:

```
{"ClassName":"System.AggregateException","Message":"One or more errors occurred.","Data":null,"InnerException":{"ClassName":"Microsoft.Azure.Documents.DocumentClientException","Message":"Message: {\"Errors\":[\"Owner resource does not exist\"]}\r\nActivityId: 89bb346d-762d-430f-a1cb-dc4a3c55ac24, Request URI: /apps/bfb8961c-dcec-4c64-b341-400abf86ebdb/services/2ace1923-f76e-454f-9e2a-ea3a454dfb82/partitions/179a8dae-314e-4c15-878e-715cbb0e4f2e/replicas/131142481735385314s","Data":null,"InnerException":null,"HelpURL":null,"StackTraceString":"   at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Client.ClientExtensions.<ParseResponseAsync>d__4.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Routing.GatewayAddressCache.<ResolveAddressesViaGatewayAsync>d__11.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Routing.GatewayAddressCache.<ResolveServerAsync>d__a.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Routing.GatewayAddressCache.<ResolveAsync>d__0.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.AddressSelector.<ResolveAddressesAsync>d__15.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.AddressSelector.<ResolveAllUriAsync>d__5.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.StoreReader.<ReadMultipleReplicasInternalAsync>d__a.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.StoreReader.<ReadMultipleReplicaAsync>d__0.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.ConsistencyReader.<ReadSessionAsync>d__8.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.ReplicatedResourceClient.<InvokeAsync>d__b.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.ReplicatedResourceClient.<>c__DisplayClass1.<<InvokeAsync>b__0>d__3.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.BackoffRetryUtility`1.<>c__DisplayClassd`1.<<ExecuteAsync>b__c>d__f.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.BackoffRetryUtility`1.<ExecuteRetry>d__16.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.BackoffRetryUtility`1.<ExecuteAsync>d__12`1.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.ReplicatedResourceClient.<InvokeAsync>d__7.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.StoreClient.<ProcessMessageAsync>d__0.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Client.DocumentClient.<ExecuteQueryAsync>d__2f0.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Query.DocumentQueryClient.<ExecuteQueryAsync>d__4.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Query.DocumentQueryExecutionContextBase.<ExecuteQueryRequestAsync>d__47.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Query.DefaultDocumentQueryExecutionContext.<ExecuteOnceAsync>d__9.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.BackoffRetryUtility`1.<>c__DisplayClass2.<<ExecuteAsync>b__1>d__4.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.BackoffRetryUtility`1.<ExecuteRetry>d__16.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.BackoffRetryUtility`1.<ExecuteAsync>d__7.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Query.DefaultDocumentQueryExecutionContext.<ExecuteInternalAsync>d__6.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Query.DocumentQueryExecutionContextBase.<ExecuteNextAsync>d__11.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.R
```

There are two instances of the IReliableReadWriteDocumentClient that are created in a static constructor provider class (one per Db) that lookup two collections.

Update2: 
Looking into it further, comparing the requests to the address routing table, the ReadCollection method (which 404s) targets the primary node, but the CreateCollection method (which 409s) is targeting a secondary node.
Also I'm working a repro, it may take a little time unfortunately.

Comment: We had a similar problem. At first we thought that it was a DocumentDB bug, but after poking at it a bit, we realized that we had a subtle race condition. The easiest way to fix this was by adding a short delay. This was OK, in our case, because it only happened in test code and then more rarely in startup code, but your situation might not allow for that. If that's the case, look for and remove the race condition. You want to make sure there is zero chance that an operation on a collection occurs before the call to create the collection is done.